# Wireshark filter for packets which initiates FIN (connection close) sequence from the server-side

Tags: apache, tcp, wireshark, amazon-elb, packet-capture

```
Apache (ec2) --- Client (ELB)
|                      |
|-------[1.]FIN------->|
|                      |
|<-----[2.]FIN+ACK-----|
|                      |
|---------ACK--------->|
|                      |
```

With Wireshark I'd like to extract only the packet "[1.]FIN" described above figure which is emitted by server's 80 port and which "initiates" FIN sequence.

I've tried a filter:

> tcp.flags.fin && tcp.srcport==80

but the filter also extracts the extra "[2.]FIN+ACK" packets.
How can I filter out only [1.] packet considering "FIN" sequence initiator?

Background:

I'm struggling to get rid of 504 errors with AWS ELB and ec2 (apache), where "FIN - FIN/ACK - ACK" sequence is initiated by the backend apache-side. In such environment FIN sequence initiated by ELB is ideal as AWS official sais: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html

According to https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/504-error-classic/, I've tried changing replace MPM (event -> worker) and disabling TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT, which slightly reduced 504 errors. However the situation is not much improved.

The point I think will be to find the cause which makes apache initiate active-close sequence, thus I'm firstly trying to extract initiating FIN packet from apache among at most 512 parallel connections between ELB and EC2 (apache).

Comment: The cause will be server-side expiry of a kept-alive HTTP connection.

Comment: Apache's KeepaliveTimeout is set to 120 while ELB idle timeout is set to 60 thus that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

> tcp.flags.fin == 1 && tcp.flags.ack == 0

- A filter such as tcp.flags.fin only checks for the presence of the parameter.  To find certain values of a parameter, a comparison is needed.  That is why filters like "tcp" work to find TCP packets.
- The filter match for FIN does not exclude other flags being set or not set, so a comparison is needed for each flag that should be part of the filter.